# ASP.Net Grid View return to page index

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pager

I know others have had a similar issue as me, but no one so far seems to have a solution to it. Basically, I have a simple GridView with a pager and I can get the page index from it (GridView1.PageIndex etc..). But how can I retain this when a user clicks on a hyperlink bound in the Gridview to another page, update some details, then come back to the page with the GridView. So they go to page 4, click the link, update details, then go back.

I can set the value in the session and get it form the page I go to, but on databound I am checking for it and trying to set it, but it just does not work. Is there a built-in function that Microsoft thought of?

Comment: You might think of it as going back to that record when you come back, not going back to page 4.   Going back to that record will happen to be page 4 but you code is displaying the page with record id 12345.  If you put "go to record" logic in your post or get then you can reuse that code to always go to a specific record from many pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after sucking on some caffeine I discovered that I needed to set the new Page Number on PageIndexedChanged to a session variable (best option) and on DataBinding check the session and if it exists, get the value and apply it, otherwise set it to 0 (page 1) - works a treat, hope it helps someone else.